# Connecting Windows PC to Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter (Miracast)

Tags: windows, miracast

I connected a Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter (Miracast receiver) to my TV sitting right next to the PC. It works flawlessly from my Android phone, but I'm unable to  connect to it from my custom built Windows 8.1 PC (specs below).

When I click the "Add a wireless display" link, the Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter is found.  When I click it, I briefly see a "Follow any instructions on your television", but the TV displays nothing different from the classic "Ready to connect" message and after a while I get the "That didn't work" message on the PC.

The relevant PC specs are (please see here for msinfo and dxdiag report http://1drv.ms/1z6M2e0 ):

- Intel Core i5 3570K (Sandy Bridge, 3rd generation)
- Intel HD Graphics 400 - driver 15.33.30.64.3958, reported by Windows as 10.18.10.3958 (this one https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24329 )
- Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 - driver 17.1.0.19 (this one https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24220 )
- Gigabyte GA-Z77M-D3H

The PC is already up-to-date with all the Windows Update patches.

The "Intel(R) WiDi Update Tool" reports a "go".

I already tried to format the PC clean, do a full Windows 8.1 reinstall, fully update the new installation via Windows Update and reinstall said Intel drivers: same outcome.

In the clean install, I didn't have any other network driver such as Virtual Box, Cisco VPN or the like.

I disabled both Windows Firewall and Windows Defender (no other security software are installed).

Event Viewer doesn't report a thing.

The firmware of the receiver itself is only updateable with the provided Windows Store App after the connection is established.

I switched the adapter from the TV-provided power to a wall outlet: no difference.

I reset the adapter with the dedicated button, also tried to reboot TV and PC multiple times.

As a side-note (but I'd prefer to not focus on it: I'm only mentioning it as proof that the adapter isn't failed), I noticed that when I tried to connect from the clean install before installing Windows 8.1 Update 1 (and probably some others I cannot isolate) the computer briefly connected and the TV sensed it providing a "Enter this PIN on your PC" message, but the PIN prompt never appeared on the PC screen.

What should I do to diagnose or fix the problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to connect miracast for my Roku box and found they were on different networks Might seem the obvious question but are both on the same WiFi

Comment: No, they are not. Miracast doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found and fixed. My Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 is a notebook card (Mini PCI-E) mounted inside my desktop PC via a PCIe x1 adapter. The adapter only has one antenna connector (a so called "U.FL / IPX to RP SMA male PIGTAIL") in bundle, but the card has two antenna pin (one "main" and one "aux"). I connected the single pin to the "main" connector on the card and, since the Wi-Fi was working ok, I erroneously thought it was enough. I forgot about that until I re-opened the card to check if the card was somehow unseated.

I rushly bought a second antenna connector for the "aux" port and presto! now it works flawlessly!

Have a nice xmas!